# Make div (with behaviour like button created with JS) into link if javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, noscript

I have 6 div's that have onclick javascript.
When you click them a part of the site changes.

I want these divs to contain links if javascript is disabled. (instead of changing the part of the page link to another page)

How would I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<div>
   <a href="noscript.htm" onclick="window.location='script.htm';return false;">button</a>
</div>
```

something like this?​
http://jsfiddle.net/C6BJT/

Comment: I did this:
<a href="noscript.html" onclick="return false"><div onclick="js_on()">Button<div></a> | Easier than Stijn_d's solution. (wish I could upvote you but I don't have the rank)

Comment: @Anton, downvote for teaching to use inline JavaScript in 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a link in the html and swap it with js when you need it to be a button?